# linebreaks for cjk languages?

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, languages, cjk, japanese

What do I need to write documents in a CJK language? I'm getting no linebreaks at all on Japanese text. (overfull hboxes, text going off-page)

Here is a (mostly) stripped-down test:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{CJK}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{VL Gothic}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{VL Gothic}
すべての人間は、生れながらにして自由であり、かつ、尊厳と権利とについて平等である。人間は、理性と良心とを授けられており、互いに同胞の精神をもって行動しなければならない。
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure I'm using the CJK package correctly -- it seems to make no difference. What am I doing wrong?

I am using XeLaTeX.

Comment: This was supposed to have the tags: cjk japanese, but I'm not allowed to create new tags.

Comment: I have added a {cjk} tag. I don't think a {japanese} tag is needed, as we don't have any tags for other languages either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xeCJK` instead if you're using XeLaTeX. Also, use `\setCJKmainfont` for VL Gothic,  reserving `\setmainfont` for selecting a font for non-CJK characters. The `CJK` environment is not required when using `xeCJK`.

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Helvetica}
\setCJKmainfont{VL Gothic}

\begin{document}
This is some English text.
すべての人間は、生れながらにして自由であり、かつ、尊厳と権利とについて平等である。人間は、理性と良心とを授けられており、互いに同胞の精神をもって行動しなければならない。
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that a minimal setting for CJK languages?

Comment: @Yiannis As a matter of fact, fontspec, xunicode and xltxtra are not required. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should not combine `CJK` with `XeLaTeX`. `CJK` is designed for `LaTeX`, you need to install the fonts for `TeX` system, which is not very easy. `xeCJK` is a xe-version of `CJK`, used mainly by simplified Chinese.

`XeLaTeX` support instinct CJK fonts itself. xeCJK is of course more sophiscated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}%save as utf-8, run xelatex
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{ＭＳ Ｐ明朝}%I changed the font
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "ja" % linebreak, otherwise all will in one line
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt minus 0.1pt  

\begin{document}
すべての人間は、生れながらにして自由であり、かつ、尊厳と権利とについて平等である。人間 は、理性と良心とを授けられており、互いに同胞の精神をもって行動しなければならない。

\end{document}
```